# spring batch job with multi-threading does not working

Tags: spring, spring-batch

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job processJob;

private ExecutorService executorService;

@Override
public AiResponseDTO executeAiRules(AiRequestDTO aiRequestDTO) throws Exception {
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(aiRequestDTO.getAiRuleTypes().size());
            for(AiRuleType aiRuleType: aiRequestDTO.getAiRuleTypes()) {
                if(aiRuleType!=AiRuleType.HVAC) {
                    System.out.println("Start : "+aiRuleType.getValue()+" : "+new Date());
                    try {
                        Future<?> submit = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    //add custom job parameters and start job
                                    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                                            .addDouble("random", Math.random())
                                            .addParameter("customparam",
            new AiJobCustomParameter(aiRequestDTO.getRequestedFile(),
                                                            aiRequestDTO.getAiEmsType(),
                                                            aiRuleType,
                                                            zipFileExtractedPath,
                                                            tmpFileStorePath)).toJobParameters();
                                    jobLauncher.run(processJob,jobParameters);
                                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException
                                        | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        aiMap.put(aiRuleType, submit);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
```

> I am trying to run multiple job instance in parallel with multi threading for execute different task. Also i am using threadPoolTaskExecuter for jobs and using MultiResourcePartitioner for partition the csv files. but it does not work like it should be. The every next job is waiting to finish previous.

```
@Configuration
public class AiJobBatchConfig {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

private AiJobCustomParameter jobParameters;

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws 
Exception {
 SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
 jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
 jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(jobLauncherTaskExecutor());
 jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
 return jobLauncher;
}
@Bean
public Job processJob() throws IOException, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob").incrementer(
new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(new AiJobListener())
            //.flow(masterStep())
            .start(masterStep())
            //.end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step masterStep() throws IOException, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").listener(new StepExecutionListener() {

        @Override
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            jobParameters = (AiJobCustomParameter)stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters().getParameters().get("customparam");
        }

        @Override
        public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            return null;
        }
    })
            .partitioner(executerStep().getName(),partitioner())
            .step(executerStep())
            .taskExecutor(jobLauncherTaskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step executerStep() throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("executerStep")
            .<String,Object> chunk(1000)
            .reader(new AiFileReader())
            .processor(new AiFileProcessor())
            .writer(new AiFileWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Partitioner partitioner() {
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    try {
        Resource[] resources2 = resolver.getResources("file:"+jobParameters.getZipFileExtractedPath()+"*");
        for(Resource resource : resources2) {
            //System.out.println("R1 : "+resource.getFilename());
            if(resource.getFilename().endsWith(".csv")) {
                resources.add(resource);
            }
            //check inside the folder and fetch files
            else if(!resource.getFilename().endsWith(".*")) {
                Resource[] resources3 = resolver.getResources(resource.getURI()+"/*");
                for(Resource resource2 : resources3) {
                        resources.add(resource2);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Resource [] resources2 =resources.toArray(new Resource[resources.size()]);
    if(resources2.length==0)
        logger.error("NO CSV FILE FOUND");
    logger.error("Resources : "+resources2.length);
    partitioner.setResources(resources2);
    return partitioner;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor jobLauncherTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
    return executor;
}
}
```

If I use corePoolSize it allows to parallel execution for job instances but than all files are not execute for every job. Total files are divided into job instances.

Comment: Your question does not introduce the user in any way. Try to provide an overview about the topic

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Batch uses a `SyncTaskExecutor` for the job launcher which is single threaded. You did not share the configuration of your job launcher (so I guess the default one is being used). You need to make sure to use an asynchronous task executor for your `JobLauncher`, like the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` (which is fine for testing purpose, but not suitable for production as it does not reuse threads) or the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. Here is an example:

```
// this is your current task executor
@Bean
public TaskExecutor jobLauncherTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
    return executor;
}

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(jobLauncherTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

You can find more details in the [Configuring a JobLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: It does not help. I want to run three job instances in parallel on three different threads. but if i use Task-executor without set corePoolSize jobs are not execute in parallel. every next job is waiting to finish current job. and if I set  corePoolSize my totals files are divided into total job instances. So every job does not read all the file resource.

Comment: It should, you did not share your job launcher config. Please edit the question and share its config. You are putting `jobLauncher.run(processJob,jobParameters);` in a loop, which means multiple jobs are submitted to the job launcher, but if the launcher if backed by a synchronous task executor, it is not surprising that jobs are not executed in parallel and each job will wait until the previous one is finished.

Comment: I have provide the same job launcher congif. But it does not help. Job instances are still running one by one.

Comment: That should not be the case. The config I shared in my answer should allow you to run submitted jobs in parallel. If it still does not work, your problem is elsewhere.